# Python peewee / fastapi get User without loading Items

Tags: python, peewee, fastapi

So I followed this tutorial to kombine fastapi & peewee:
[link](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sql-databases-peewee/)

And due to this tutorial i got those models (peewee):

```
class User(peewee.Model):
    email = peewee.CharField(unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = peewee.CharField()
    is_active = peewee.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        database = db


class Item(peewee.Model):
    title = peewee.CharField(index=True)
    description = peewee.CharField(index=True)
    owner = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User, backref="items")

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

And those basemodels (fastapi):

```
class PeeweeGetterDict(GetterDict):
    def get(self, key: Any, default: Any = None):
        res = getattr(self._obj, key, default)
        if isinstance(res, peewee.ModelSelect):
            return list(res)
        return res


class ItemBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: Optional[str] = None


class ItemCreate(ItemBase):
    pass


class Item(ItemBase):
    id: int
    owner_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        getter_dict = PeeweeGetterDict


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str


class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    is_active: bool
    items: List[Item] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        getter_dict = PeeweeGetterDict
```

I have this to call the api:

```
database.db.connect()
database.db.create_tables([User, Item])
database.db.close()

app = FastAPI()

def get_db(db_state=Depends(reset_db_state)):
    try:
        database.db.connect()
        yield
    finally:
        if not database.db.is_closed():
            database.db.close()

@app.get("/users/", response_model=List[schemas.User], dependencies=[Depends(get_db)])
def read_users():
    return list(models.User.select()
```

**This is the base. Now begins my problem / question:**

If I call this request (GET "/users/"), I get the following JSON as a result (the data is imaginary its only about the structure)

```
[
    {
        "email": "123@test.com"
        "id": 1
        "is_active": 1
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "item1"
                "description": "placeholder"
                "id": "1"
                "owner_id": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is how it is supposed to be **BUT** i don't want it exactly like this. I want that I **only** get the user data, without its items.

So... my question:

*How can I get the user data without loading the data of the items?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to do that, `response_model_exclude` is exactly what you are looking for.

```
@app.get("/users/", response_model=List[schemas.User], response_model_exclude={"items"}, dependencies=[Depends(get_db)])
def read_users():
    return list(models.User.select()
```

Ref: [FastAPI Response Model](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#response_model_include-and-response_model_exclude)